# Python connect to an external server using sockets

Tags: python, sockets, ip, port, portforwarding

I am trying to build a connection between a server and one or more clients in Python using sockets. My code works just fine when I connect with a client in the same network, but my goal is to build a program which me and my friend can use, so I want to figure out a way to connect to my server from an external network via the internet.

**My server-side code looks like this:**

```
import socket

server = "internal_ip"
port = 5006

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    serv.bind((server, port))
    print(server)
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)

serv.listen(2)

while True:
    conn, addr = serv.accept()
    from_client = ""
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            break
        from_client += str(data)
        print(from_client)
        conn.send(str.encode("I am SERVER"))
    conn.close()
    print("Client disconnected")
```

**And this is my client:**

```
import socket

server = "internal_ip"
port = 5006

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    client.connect((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)
    
while True:
    try:
        client.send(str.encode("I am CLIENT"))
        from_server = client.recv(4096)
    #client.close()
        print(from_server)
    except:
        break
client.close()
```

This works just fine within a network. Then I started testing the code from an external client. I changed  the ip to my external ip address which I have found using whatismyipaddress.com, and port number to a different one than I use on the server side.

```
server = "external_ip"
port = 5007
```

Then I enabled port forwarding using cmd:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5007 listenaddress=external_ip connectport=5006 connectaddress=internal_ip
```

I get WinError 10060. Tried switching firewall on and off, and allowing these specific ports, but I can't make it work.

Can you help me with my problem please?

Comment: Try using ngrok, you can find tons of tutorial about it